# Apply some picture to the circle graphic in the as3

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flashdevelop, bitmapdata

So, I already have the circle in my screen and showed it up, but I wanted to change the graphic from the "default circle", which is created by using the code like so:

```
circle.graphic.BeginFill();
circle.graphic.DrawCircle(10,10,10);
circle.graphic.EndFill();
addChild(circle);
```

I wanted to change that to my desired image like so:

[image]

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BitmapData` and `beginBitmapFill`  with circle like so:

```
var myBitmap:BitmapData;

var imgLoader:Loader = new Loader();
imgLoader.load(new URLRequest("myImage.png"));
imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, drawImage);


function drawImage(e:Event):void
{
    myBitmap = new BitmapData(imgLoader.width, imgLoader.height, false);
    myBitmap.draw(imgLoader);

    var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();
    circle.graphics.beginBitmapFill(myBitmap, null, true);
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(50,50,100);
    circle.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(circle);
}
```

For more info see [`beginBitmapFill()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginBitmapFill%28%29)